# Can't use enum variants when using enum as a generic type?

Tags: generics, rust, enums

I'm having a E0599 (no associated item named `Variant1` found for type parameter `MyEnum` in the current scope) error with the following code :

```rust
enum MyEnum {
    Variant1,
    Variant2,
    Variant3
}

struct MyStruct {}

trait MyTrait<T> {
    fn get_some_variant(self) -> T;
}

impl<MyEnum> MyTrait<MyEnum> for MyStruct {
    fn get_some_variant(self) -> MyEnum {
        MyEnum::Variant1
    }
}
```

Here is a [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9737ebae922d5bcb47ca1e278792c979).

Why can't I build a variant from my enum in this case ?

What are the workaround ? Are enums not meant to be used as generics ?

Comment: Change  `impl<MyEnum> MyTrait<MyEnum> for MyStruct` to just `impl MyTrait<MyEnum> for MyStruct` [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b3100bf33f386748e2031bb5214f1af0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`impl<MyEnum>` defines `MyEnum` as an arbitrary generic type, which is shadowing your actual `MyEnum` definition.

```rust
impl MyTrait<MyEnum> for MyStruct {
    fn get_some_variant(self) -> MyEnum {
        MyEnum::Variant1
    }
}
```

works as expected and creates an implementation for `MyTrait<MyEnum>`.